# Use IDENT_CURRENT() to get my ID during insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

Say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [ExampleTable]
(
    [ExampleID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ExampleCompositeNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Certificates] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ExampleID] ASC)
)
```

What I would like, is the `[ExampleCompositeNumber]` to be `ExampleID-[000000-999999]`.

I was hoping this insert would work, but I am concerned about two people inserting at the same time, and the wrong ID being assigned to the first part of `ExampleCompositeNumber`

```
INSERT INTO ExampleTable (ExampleCompositeNumber)
VALUES (CAST(IDENT_CURRENT('ExampleTable') AS nvarchar(18)) + '-123345')
```

When I have used `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `IDENT_CURRENT` I get the previously inserted ID, not the ID of the insert I am currently making. Here is a sample of what that insert would look like:

```
INSERT INTO ExampleTable (ExampleCompositeNumber)
VALUES (CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS nvarchar(18)) + '-123345')
```

Am I correct in my concern or is there a possibility of overlap if multiple inserts are happening?

Comment: The way you are trying to call it, you would be trying to access the identity before it has been populated... its only available after the insert... not during. And if you read the documentation regarding `IDENT_CURRENT` you will find out how concurrency works. But Marc's answer it the correct approach anyway.

Comment: @DaleK, `IDENT_CURRENT` does work as I would hope it would, but my worry was what the [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16](documentation) said. 

For context a process in an Access app I run uses a DAO recordset to populate the ID without fail for many years. I was just hoping to replicate that in SQL Server.

Comment: OK TIL :) thats quite unusual behaviour that the identity value is available mid-insert. I feel you should be safe, because the insert must comply with ACID, hence the id returned should be your id. But don't quote me on that. If you truly have to take this approach I would ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ because there are some folks on there who understand the SQL Server engine inside and out. Of course though, everyone is going to suggest better solutions, like the one below - and if you can use a better solution then you should.

Comment: [For the last time, NO, you can't trust IDENT_CURRENT()](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current).

Comment: Why bother with doing this during an insert. Seems to me a computed column would be a LOT simpler. Of course appending a hard coded value in every single row of a table like this is a major red flag.

Comment: @AaronBertrand so even though in this case 'ident_current' is being used within its *own* insert, you think there is still a chance it could have been changed by another session?

Comment: @SeanLange as OP has explained they are dealing with legacy code.

Comment: @DaleK Possibly, but the more salient point is, there's just no good reason to use it ever, even in the rare case where all the stars might align.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - agreed I wouldn't trust it even if it *should* work.

Answer (score 8):

In general, I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `IDENT_CURRENT()` to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

But here in this situation, I believe the best solution is to use:

- your `ExampleID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ExampleTable
(
    ExampleID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    ExampleComposite AS 'ExampleID-' + 
                         RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ExampleID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) + '-123345' PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
)
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `ExampleTable` without specifying values for `ExampleID` or `ExampleComposite`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ExampleTable(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will increase your `ExampleID` value, and `ExampleComposite` will contain values like `ExampleID-000001-123345`, `ExampleID-000002-123345`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

Comment: I did do some testing with `scope_identity()` and it always returned the previous ID, not my current one. I am debating on the computed column, but that second number is provided by another table and is passed during insert

Comment: Is there not a decent duplicate for this? It seems to get asked quite frequently.

Comment: I couldn't find one that tackles my specific question @DaleK. All of them requested the ID as a separate query.

Comment: *"I did do some testing with scope_identity() and it always returned the previous ID"* then, perhaps you were referencing it too early, or to late. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is certainly the way to go. If it's not working as you expect, then you should provide a [mre], @Elias .

Comment: @ThomA I reference it during insert. I do not want to touch the record twice if I can help it. I added a sample of what the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` insert would look like.

Comment: You should be `INSERT`ing, assigning the value of `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to a variable, and then referencing that, @Elias, rather than using it in the DML statement immediately afterwards.

Comment: @ThomA I don't disagree but I am a bit limited by what I am developing in. It is an MSAccess database frontend.